# how to get same name of csv file as the name of sql file in python

Tags: python, csv

i have several sql query files. i am trying to run each file one by one and generate csv file for each sql query. But i want to CSV file name as the name of sql file name.
example-
while the time of running survey_cust.txt sql file that time csv file survey_cust.csv will generate.
sql file - "survey_cust.txt"
generate csv file - "survey_cust.csv"

```
                path1 = "D:/Users/SPate233/Downloads/NS dashboard/sql_query/*.txt"
                files = glob.glob(path1)
                i = 1
                for name in files:
                    try:
                        with open(name) as f:
                            sql_query = f.read()
                            cur.execute(sql_query)
                            result = cur.fetchall()

                            with open("output_%s.csv" % i, 'w') as fp:
                                a = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',')
                                a.writerow([i[0] for i in cur.description])
                                a.writerows(result)
                            i+=1

                    except:
                        print("error")
```

Comment: I can't spot anything obviously wrong with this approach so you will need to elaborate on what your issue is

Comment: And what is your error?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to parse the SQL file path to get the file name, and use it for the csv file name.

```
csv_name = os.path.split(name)[1].split('.')[0] + ".csv"
#os.path.split(name)[1] gets you the file name with the extension (txt?)
#split by the extension and get the name, then add csv extension
with open(csv_name, 'w') as fp:
...
```

Is that what you were asking?

Answer (score 0):

Use `os.path.basename`:

```
import os
filename = os.path.basename('/root/dir/sub/file.txt')
# > filename = 'file.txt'
```

then simply replace the extention:

```
fname, fext = os.path.splitext(filename)
csvfile = '{0}.csv'.format(fname)
```

Or just:

```
name = '/root/dir/sub/file.txt'
csvfile = '{0}.csv'.format(os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(name))[0])
```